# awk command to sum pairs of lines and filter out under particular condition

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with numbers and I want to sum numbers from two lines and this for each column, then in my last step I want to filter out pairs of lines that has a count bigger or equal than 3 of '0' sum counts. I write a small example to make it clear:

This is my file (without the comments ofc), it contains 2 pairs of lines (=4 lines) with 5 columns.

```
2 6 0 8 9  # pair 1.A
0 1 0 5 1  # pair 1.B
0 2 0 3 0  # pair 2.A
0 0 0 0 0  # pair 2.B
```

And I need to sum up pairs of lines so I get something like this (intermediate step)

```
2 7 0 13 10 # sum pair 1, it has one 0 
0 2 0 3 0   # sum pair 2, it has three 0
```

Then I want to print the original lines, but only those which the sum of 0 (of the sum of the two lines) is lower than 3, therefore I should get printed this:

```
2 6 0 8 9  # pair 1.A
0 1 0 5 1  # pair 1.B
```

Because the sum of the second pair of lines has three `0`, then it should be excluded

So from the first file I need to get the last output.

So far what I have been able to do is to sum pairs of lines, count zeros, and identify those with a count lower than 3 of `0` but I don't know how to print the two lines that contributed to the SUM, I am only able to print one of the two lines (the last one). This is the awk I am using:

```
  awk '
  NR%2 { split($0, a); next } 
  { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (a[i]+$i == 0) SUM +=1; 
  if (SUM < 3) print $0; SUM=0 }' myfile
```

(That's what I get now)

```
0 1 0 5 1 # pair 1.B
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another variation, could be useful to avoid loop iterations in some input cases:

```
awk '!(NR%2){ zeros=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if(a[i]+$i==0) zeros++; if(zeros>=3) next } 
     print prev ORS $0 }{ split($0,a); prev=$0 }' file
```

The output:

```
2 6 0 8 9
0 1 0 5 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after digging a little bit more I found that it was rather simple to print the previous line (I was complicating myself)

```
  awk '
  NR%2 { split($0, a) ; b=$0; next } 
  { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (a[i]+$i == 0) SUM +=1; 
  if (SUM < 3) print b"\n"$0; SUM=0}' myfile
```

So I just have to save the first line in a variable `b` and print when the condition is favorable.
Hope it can help other people too

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
!(NR%2) {
    split(prev,p)
    zeroCnt = 0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        zeroCnt += (($i + p[i]) == 0 ? 1 : 0)
    }
    if (zeroCnt < 3) {
        print prev ORS $0
    }
}
{ prev = $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2 6 0 8 9
0 1 0 5 1
```